# Android Google maps get updated with Google maps - right?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am asking a question to confirm a suspicion, but I just want to make sure before I respond to my client. Some of the consumers of the app have complained that the Android maps(using Google maps) are not getting updated when Google maps, like on the web. My first thought is that this is false. I assume, and couldn't find otherwise, that when Google maps gets updated, that the map on the Android devices will like get updated.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that they do.  I've seen Satellite View updates without have an update to the actual Maps app.

Answer (score 1):

The two may not be perfectly in sync if they query different servers : Google always apply its changes by gradual rollouts.
So if you query one server that has already received the update on the desktop whereas the one queried on your mobile has not received it yet, you may spot a discrepancy. But it should be a very rare occurence.